# What's causing -EPERM to be returned as 4294967295?

Tags: c, linux

I'm hijacking a particular system call with a kernel module I'm writing. The code for the replacement is this:

```
asmlinkage int custom_setxattr(const char* __user path, const char* __user name, const void* __user value, size_t size, int flags) {
    if (!strncmp("security.checksum.", name, 18) {
        return -EPERM;
    }
    return real_setxattr(path, name, value, size, flags);
}
```

Running strace with the module prints out an analysis with this line in it:

```
setxattr("file", "security.checksum.value", "Test", 4, 0) = 4294967295
```

The C type `int` is **signed**, so I should not be seeing the value 4294967295 (what one gets when interpreting -1 as an unsigned integer). This has actually been happening with another one of my system call interceptions, but not others. Why is this? `setxattr` is capable of returning `-EPERM`.

Comment: What version of strace are you using?

Comment: `4.8-1ubuntu5` is what `dpkg` returns.

Comment: What happens if you change the return type to `long`?

Comment: Hmm...if you have the function return `-1` and set errno to `EPERM`, does that change anything? That is the way `setxattr` is supposed to report errors; not setting `errno` may confuse `strace`. This is a shot in the dark, mind you.

Comment: Changing the return type to `long` didn't change anything.

Comment: I thought `errno` is hardly used by the kernel's developers.

Comment: @Wintermute: `errno` didn't work either. Do I need to include a proper file to use it? And the code for the system call does not use any variable named `errno`.

Comment: @Dmitri: Just notifying you of the above.

Comment: @Dmitri and @Wintermute: Removing the conditional statement and making my replacement simply pass its arguments along to the real `setxattr` results in `-1 ENODATA (No data available)` and `setfattr` say "No such attribute". This also happens if I try to set an attributes whose name does trigger the `if` statement.

Comment: did you remember to #include <errno.h> ?

Comment: @user3629249: It's a kernel module. `errno.h` is not available to it and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that strace isn't smart enough to know which system calls return signed values and which return unsigned, so it's just printing unsigned values for everything.  As you pointed out, if one reinterprets the 32-bit twos-complement representation of -1 as an unsigned 32-bit integer, one gets 4294967295.  And at least on my system, `EPERM` is defined as `1`.  So `EPERM`, expressed as an unsigned 32-bit integer, is `4294967295`.

Comment: No, `strace` has returned `setxattr` with `-1 EPERM operation not permitted` before. This module changes that somehow.